# javascript convert enterkey to tabkey for all browsers(IE,Firefox,Opera,Google chrome)

Tags: javascript

I want solution to this problem,In Asp.Net convert enterkey to tabkey for all browsers(IE,Firefox,Opera,Google chrome).give me example..

```
<html>
<script> 
function enterToTab(event){
   var key = event.keyCode 
   if(key==13)
   {

    event.keyCode =9;
     return true;

   }
return false;
}

</script>
<body>
<form name='frm' >
   <table>
   <tr>
      <td><input type = text name="A" tabindex=1 id="elem1"
onkeydown="enterToTab(event);"><td>
      <td><select type = select name="B" tabindex=3 id="elem3"
onkeydown="enterToTab(event);">

      <option value = "R" selected>Red
      <option value = "B">Blue
      <option value = "G">Green
      </select><td>
      <td><input type = text name="C" tabindex=2 id="elem2"
onkeydown="enterToTab(event);"><td>
      <tr>
      <td><input type = text name="D" tabindex=4 id="elem4"
onkeydown="enterToTab(event);"><td>

      <td><textarea name="E" tabindex=6 id="elem6"></textarea>
      <td>
      <td><input type = text name="F" tabindex=5 id="elem5"
onkeydown="enterToTab(event);">
      <input type = text name="F" tabindex=7 id="elem7"
onkeydown="enterToTab(event);"><td>
      <tr>
      <table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a "do this for me" website. Show that you tried to solve it yourself. See also [ask].

Comment: i have convert key code 13 1e, enter to tab key ie, keycode 8 but this is not working in chrome, and fire fox

Comment: Please post your code and preferably, create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.keyCode is writeable only in MSIE, so you can't simply "convert" this function to make it work cross-browser.

**You**'ll need a more complex script that parses the document to build a stack of elements affected by tab-inputs(those having a tabIndex-property >0) and give them the focus accordingly to the current element.

What else: for me the TAB has keyCode 9

Comment: thanks  to molle ,keycode is 9. this is working in ie. but i want a script to support all other browser. if you know please share it. which is very helpfull to me.